# append lines after a particular line in .ssh/config file using bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Let me rephrase the total question.
I got already the config file for all vpcs using below script

```
 #!/bin/bash
VPC="$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -r '.Vpcs[] | .VpcId')"
for x in $VPC
do
  echo $x
  aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=$x" | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | (.Tags[]//[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value) as $name | "Host \($name) \nHostname \(.PrivateIpAddress)"'
done
```

and this gave me output vpc wise with Host and Hostname like this

```
  vpc-agdh5j6j
    Host remote-server1
    Hostname 123.45.6.6
    Host remote-server2
    Hostname 456.4.56.7
    vpc-guh5jk6y
    Host remote-server3
    Hostname 245.24.789.9
    Host remote-server4
    Hostname 457.87.1.7
    .
    .
    .
```

so on
Now i saved this output to a file and trying to add one more line after Hostname wherever it exists in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "user         : "$1
    VPC="$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -r '.Vpcs[] | .VpcId')"
    for x in $VPC
    do
      echo $x
      aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=$x" | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | (.Tags[]//[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value) as $name | "Host \($name) \nHostname \(.PrivateIpAddress)"' > config.txt
      sed -i '/^Hostname.*/a User\t$1' config.txt
      cat config.txt
    done
```

Here user is passed as an argument and is passing to script as mentioned above. It is not taking the input value given to "user" and is simply displaying in the output as $1 only.
Its giving the output as below.

```
 vpc-agdh5j6j
    Host remote-server1
    Hostname 123.45.6.6
    User $1
    Host remote-server2
    Hostname 456.4.56.7
    User $1
    vpc-guh5jk6y
    Host remote-server3
    Hostname 245.24.789.9
    User $1
    Host remote-server4
    Hostname 457.87.1.7
    User $1
    .
    .
so on
```

Its not taking value given in the argument.

Comment: Just post the code you already have so far and explain, at which point you are stuck.

Comment: Also, you did not specify where the number after `jump` comes from. BTW, given the form of your input, I would write this in awk, not in bash.

Comment: the number after jump is nothing but just the names of bastion servers via which user has to jump to connect to remote servers.  I was having a script where it will list all vpcs, and for each vpc, it will give the output with Host and Hostname

Comment: its the same mentioned above. Iam new to scripting so i could not able to modify with the new output what i mentioned. can you suggest how can i append extra line?

Comment: Printing lines from bash is done using `echo` or `printf`. From awk (if you decided to go this way), the command for printing a line is `print`.

Comment: i tried using this command to add new line after Hostname everywhere 
sed '/^HostName.*/a User\tubuntu' config.txt 
But it is not adding giving the same output with host and host name

Comment: I don't see any `sed` command in your post. Amend your question to show the actual code you are using.

Comment: In your question, _gave me output in .ssh/config_  is unclear to me. I don't see where in your code you would write to `.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a 100% fit as your requirements are a bit unclear, but this should get you started.

```
sed "s/^ *\(HostName .*\)/    \1\n    User ${username}\n    ProxyJump ${jump}\n/" ~/.ssh/config
```

Check that the output is as you would like it, then add `-i` to `sed` to make the changes in-place.

The logic:

- `s/` -- search/replace
- `^ *\(HostName .*\)` -- the line on which to act

  - `^ *` -- start of line (`^` followed by 0..n spaces)
  - `\(` -- starts a group
  - `HostName` -- verbatim string
  - `.*` -- space, followed by 0..n characters (to end of line)
  - `\)` -- ends group
- `/` -- end of search pattern, start replace pattern

  - `\1` -- four spaces, followed by the first (and only) group from the search pattern
  - `\n` -- newline
  - `User ${username}\n` -- your User entry
  - `ProxyJump ${jump}\n` -- your ProxyJump entry
- `/` -- end of replace pattern

Answer (score 0):

Script is working if i use double quotes for sed command it worked. Its taking variable value passed in the argument

```
sed -i "/^Hostname.*/a User\t$1" config.txt
```